# Any word containing only alphabet , numbers but not Q, I, O , no other character

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a program to match string with alpha numeric.I have tried on but could not find.
please tell me regular expression for alphanumeric except o, O, I, i

i have tried many , but some times one character failing, i am new to regex

```
[A-HJ-NPR-Za-hj-npr-z0-9]$
```

My requirements are:

- Takes all alphabet and number
- Need to exclude `Q`, `O` and `I` small and capital

Comment: Try ranges like 0-9 first, move P and p to the end. `'/.../i'` is case-insensitive.

Comment: Try `[^ioq]*` with `i` flag

Comment: i changed qquesiton title , please see

Comment: i tried this ^[A-HJ-NPR-Za-hj-npr-z0-9]*$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try this:

```
/[^\Wqoi]*/i
```

- `[^\W]` is same as `\w` - will take all alphanumeric characters..
- So, `[^\Woi]` is same as `\w - [oi]`
- `/i` flag is for case-insensitivity.

---

Since you don't want to match underscores, the correct regex would be:

```
/[^\Wqoi_]+/i
```

Since, `\w` also include `_`.

Comment: nice, remember `\w` contains `_` also and have to remove that also

Comment: i want only alphabet ( without case ) numbers excep Q, I, O without case

Comment: i changed question title , please see

Comment: Won't it match `"___"` even though OP wants to match only alpha numerics.

Comment: @anubhava also suggested that, regex should be `/[^\Wqoi_]+/i` with `+` instead of `*` as you're interested in at least 1 character

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
/\b(?:(?![qoi_])\w)+\b/i
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/ZbdKGOzyQg

Comment: nice, and here's a simplified version: `/(?:(?![oi_])\w)+/i`

Comment: @kaᵠ Yes that is definitely shorter but I would still keep word boundaries for obvious reasons.

Comment: i changed question title , please see

Comment: Ok changed my answer as per your edit and @kaᵠ's suggestions.